# Angular closing material dialog from dialog's child component throws errors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am closing my dialog from dialog's child component :

**Dialog.html :**

```
<ng-container>
    <app-invoice-form  [disabled]="false" [formGroup]="invoiceFormGroup" [hash]="data.hash" [afterPayment]="true">
    </app-invoice-form>
</ng-container>
```

**InvoiceForm.ts :**

```
 constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<InvoiceDialog>
  ) { }

  public goBackToOrder() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    this.router.navigate(['/cart', this.hash, true]);
  }
```

When goBackToOrder() fires, everything looks good, dialog closes, router navigates, but then after router navigates i am getting these errors in my console :

> ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CartModule)[MatDialogRef ->
> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef]:    NullInjectorError:
> No provider for MatDialogRef!

How to fix this error ?

CartModule imports MatDialogModule.

Comment: Cna you share your imports ?

Comment: From where ? 3 components are connected here. Dialog , InvoiceForm, Cart.

Comment: I was asking for import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} to show

Comment: These are imported in dialog component.

Comment: Can you show them how do you import them?

Comment: import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

Comment: Try using import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material'; without dialog in the end

Comment: its an error then, (not a module)

Comment: Add @Optional() to the injector. @Optional() public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<InvoiceDialog>